# Entry Point No Found

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un problema, cuando compilo el programa no me sale error todo bien pero cuando ejecuto el programa me dice Entry point no found y me señala el nombre de la clase y del .cpp pero no encuentro lo que esta fallando[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] estoy usando vs2003

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! dices que es vb.net, pero nombras un cpp???

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.